# Spark Data frame select nothing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

How to retrieve nothing out of a spark dataframe.

I need something like this,

> df.where("1" === "2")

I needed this so that I can do a left join with another dataframe.
Basically I am trying to avoid the data skewing while joining two dataframes by splitting the null and not null key columns and joining them separately and then do a union them.

df1 has 300M records out of which 200M records has Null keys.
df2 has another 300M records.

So to join them, I am splitting the df1 containing null and not null keys separately and then join them with df2. so to join the null key dataframe with df2, I don't need any records from df2.

I can just add the columns from df2 to null key df1, 
but curious to see if we have something like this in spark

> df.where("1" === "2")

As we do in RDBMS SQLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There many different ways, like `limit`:

```
df.limit(0)
```

where with `Column`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.where(lit(false))
```

where with `String` expression:

```
df.where("false")
```

`1 = 2` expressed as

```
df.where("1 = 2")
```

or

```
df.where(lit(1) === lit(2))
```

would work as well, but are more verbose than required.

Answer (score 1):

`where` function calls `filter` function at the internal level so you can use `filter` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.filter(lit(1) === lit(2))
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.filter(expr("1 = 2"))
```

or

```
df.filter("1 = 2")
```

or

```
df.filter("false")
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.filter(lit(false))
```

**Any expression that would return *false* in the `filter` function would work**.